# How to implement Google push notification on Java web service?

Tags: web-services, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on Google Cloud Messaging for Android. I have implemented Google Cloud Messaging on the client side. But I don't know how to implement GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) push notification on the server side (Java REST web services).
Please, can anyone send me a link or give me an idea on how to implement GCM on server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/), since your starting GCM in server side, this tutorial gives you good and understandable explanation about both client and server side coding. It also use both JAVA and PHP for the server.

Try also to check the answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758402/how-to-send-notification-to-android-app-from-java-server-using-gcm). They also give some tutorial on how to set up the server side. Hope it helps :)