# How to send notification message from my android app based on some condition

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on android app, while user registration It stores registration id(gcm id) in the database. I am having gcm id, sender id, api key. How can i send notification message to particular device by passing gcm id ?

Pls guide me with some link. I dont know php. guide me through java code.

Advance Thanks

Comment: follow this tutorial http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139

Comment: or maybe this duplication question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758402/how-to-send-notification-to-android-app-from-java-server-using-gcm

Comment: Hi Sniper, This link is working fine for manually sending messages to app. Everytime I have to type message from server to push the notification to app.  My requirement is , automatically needs to send the message to app based on the data change in the table.

Comment: Thanks brahmy. Its working fine.  I followed this link http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per  brahmy adigopula's reply, I Followed this link  http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139

Answer (score 1):

Put your data Here and send.

[**Link**](http://demo.androidhive.info/gcm_chat/push_test.php) Its for testing you can create your own panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this link : http://www.gcm-alert.appspot.com/
This is working great for send notification to particular device.

Answer (score 0):

Google says Move FCM try it .

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to make ENDPOINT for SENDER who sends message to particular id.
CODE :-

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(10000).addData("your message", message1).build();
  Result result = sender
                .send(message, gcm_id, 1);
```