# Push Notification from spring hibernate server to android client

Tags: java, android, hibernate, spring-mvc, push-notification

I am having my project in android and server as spring hibernate , middleware is Mysql. I want send push notification from server to client. how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

How about using Firebase as Cloud Messaging server. You can easily configure and use it.

```
private void sendAndroidNotification(String deviceToken,String message,String title) throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject msgObject = new JSONObject();
        msgObject.put("body", message);
        msgObject.put("title", title);
        msgObject.put("icon", ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_ICON);
        msgObject.put("color", ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_COLOR);

        obj.put("to", deviceToken);
        obj.put("notification",msgObject);

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, obj.toString());
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_URL).post(body)
                .addHeader("content-type", CONTENT_TYPE)
                .addHeader("authorization", "key="+ANDROID_NOTIFICATION_KEY).build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        logger.debug("Notification response >>>" +response.body().string());
    }
```

This example is a bit old see [source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39615679/5284441), use [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) for reference and implementation guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an implementation of [JSR356][1] ( API for WebSocket) .
It is integrated in the latest versions of tomcat and jetty . 
this an example [https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774][2]  . 
I used this implementation a long time ago https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket